# Making GPS tacking app. LocationRequest deprecated. Don't know how to solve

Tags: java, gradle, geolocation

I'm making a location-tracking app. This is the first time I'm programming in Java and I have no idea how to update the deprecated methods. I see that Android Studio is trying its best to explain how to use the current methods, but I still keep messing it up.

```
    LocationRequest locationRequest;


        locationRequest = new LocationRequest(); // LocationRequest() is deprecated

        // How often does the default location check occur?
        locationRequest.setInterval(1000 * DEFAULT_UPDATE_INTERVAL); //.setInterval() is deprecated

        // How often does the location check occur when set to the most frequent update?
        locationRequest.setFastestInterval(1000 * FAST_UPDATE_INTERVAL); // setFastestInterval is deprecated

        locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);

 // setPriority() is deprecated
// PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY constant is deprecated

        sw_gps.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (sw_gps.isChecked()) {
                    // most accurate - use GPS
                    locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);


// .setPriority method deprecated and PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY constant deprecated



                    tv_sensor.setText("Using GPS sensors");
                } else {
                    locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);
                    tv_sensor.setText("Using Towers + WiFi");


// .setPriority and PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY are deprecated


                }
            }
        });
```

So how do I fix this? The error messages I'm get when hovering over setPriority, and the constants is:

`This method is deprecated. Use LocationRequest.Builder.setIntervalMillis(long) instead. May be removed in a future release.`

`This constant is deprecated. Use Priority.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY instead.`

`This constant is deprecated. Use Priority.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY instead.`

I'm sorry if this is not very readable. It's my first time using Java to build an android app and this is the best way I could formulate the question.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It appears to be asking you to use a "builder" for `LocationRequest` instead of creating one directly. (This is most likely because they want to make `LocationRequest` read-only in the future.) Look for either `LocationRequest.builder()` or `new LocationRequest.Builder()`.

Answer (score 4):

Try using LocationRequest.Builder

Below code for creating location request

*Kotlin*

```
LocationRequest.Builder(Priority.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY, 10000)
            .apply {
                setWaitForAccurateLocation(false)
                setMinUpdateIntervalMillis(IMPLICIT_MIN_UPDATE_INTERVAL)
                setMaxUpdateDelayMillis(100000)
            }.build()
```

*Java*

```
new LocationRequest.Builder(Priority.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY, 10000)
    .setWaitForAccurateLocation(false)
    .setMinUpdateIntervalMillis(IMPLICIT_MIN_UPDATE_INTERVAL)
    .setMaxUpdateDelayMillis(100000)
    .build()
```

Read more about here https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationRequest.Builder